# Python string find() method

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, methods

I have written a below code to find a text in a variable. it is working for the outer if condition but not inner condition(same as outer).

```
name = "Sachin"

if name.find("chin"):
    print("Text Presented")
    print(name)
    if name.find("Sac"):
        print("Sac is prsented")
        print(name)
```

O/P : 
Text Presented
Sachin

But it will work for below code(searching for lower character):

```
name = "Sachin"

if name.find("chin"):
    print("Text Presented")
    print(name)
    if name.find("sac"):
        print("Sac is prsented")
        print(name)
```

O/P : 
Text Presented
Sachin
Sac is prsented
Sachin

can some one please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Both pieces of code are same.

Comment: how is this related to `pip` or `pycharm`?

Comment: updated the questions.

Comment: Why the downvoting guys? He wrote some code at least..

Comment: @Ev.Kounis he wrote same piece of code twice thats why he got much downvotes. Now, he edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening is that `name.find("Sac")` returns `0` which has a boolean value of `False` so the `if`-clause does not trigger they way you want.

Try this instead:

```
name = "Sachin"

if "chin" in name:
    print("Text present")
    print(name)
    if "Sac" in name:
        print("Sac is present")
        print(name)
```

Note: the `0` is returned by `name.find("Sac")` because `"Sac"` at `"Sachin"` begins at position 0 (Python uses 0-index).

Apart from 0-index, Python is also case-sensitive meaning `name.find("sac")` returns `-1` (which is what happens when what you are trying to `find` in the `str`ing is **not** there). However, `bool(-1) = 1` so the `if` does end up triggering and the code beneath it executes.

Comment: And to extend upon this, the second with lowercase `"sac"` returns `-1` as it is not present, which evaluates to `True` in an if statement.

Comment: i have alter the questions. can u check now

Comment: am i using in a unpythonic way?

Comment: @jaibalaji you are using a wrong way. To be *unpythonic* it has to work first.

Answer (score 2):

`name.find("chin")` will return the value `2`, which has a boolean value of `True` in python.

`name.find("Sac")` will return the value `0`, which has a boolean value of `False` in python.

`name.find("sac")` will return the value `-1`, which has a boolean value of `True` in python.

Use the `in` operator, I think this will give you the functionality you want.
See below:

```
name = "Sachin"

if "chin" in name:
    print("Text Presented")
    print(name)
    if "Sac" in name:
        print("Sac is prsented")
        print(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python [find(sub)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) method return the **lowest index** where the substring sub is found and return -1 if its not.

- In first piece of code, name.find("Sac") returns "0", because index of "S" in Sachin is "0". hence, the body of 'if' isn't executing.
- In Second piece of code, name.find("sac") returns "-1", but if(-1) is true hence the body of 'if' in this piece of code executing. I hope you will get the concept now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp for searching in string by just importing `re`

```
import re
name = "Sachin"
if re.search("chin",name):
    print("Text Presented")
    print(name)
    if re.search("Sac",name):
        print("Sac is prsented")
        print(name)
```